# measure number of times iphone turns on and off

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

Is there some way to check how many times a user unlocks his/her iPhone everyday? I thought about using the `accelerometer` or `light sensor` but I'm not sure how this would work.

Comment: No, not really. You could is `accelerometer` or `light sensor` but it will only work if you app is running in the foreground and will be a hit and miss method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible, at least for now. There's no such API in iOS currently.